# grant full privliges on opt directory to another users without ownership

Tags: linux, redhat

I am trying to provide full privileges to multiple users to do anything they want on a specific directory, and make sure no one can take ownership on any file or folder inside that directory. for example lets say the directory that I want to provide other full privileges is `/opt`;if I made the privileges for opt directory is 777 or 7777 and user1 try to create another text file then he will claim the ownership on that text file and no one will have full privileges to edit it, so I created a `cron` job to change the ownership and privileges to the default one (owner:root, and the permission level is 777) every 10 second but that created a problem for me users now can not replace or copy sub-directory (permission denied error). what did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yon can use the SGID bit to control group ownership of directories and files created within them.  For example, you could add all of the users that need access to an "optuser" group in /etc/group.  Then, change the group ownership of the directory and set the bit

```
chgrp -R optuser /opt
find /opt -type d -exec chmod g+s {} +
```

When new files are created under opt, they will  inherit the group, and all users in that group will have have write permissions if you're using the default umask.  Note that users have write access so the could change permissions and ownership of the files if they wanted to.

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful, I will study it more to change even the ownership for the user.

Answer (score 2):

You did not use POSIX ACLs. and this is what's wrong. And using cron for fixing permissions is a nightmare. Enable POSIX ACL on a filesystem, and use 'em. This way your permissions will be really flexible and complex. `man setfacl getfacl`.